# Python to stored procedures - The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a stored procedure with more than 50 parameters doing insert in a table (basically inserting a dataframe by stored procedure) on SQL Server.
When I run the code I get the following error :

> The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.

I tried the following syntaxes with always the same error :

```py
cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()
#1
df.apply(lambda row: cursor.execute('EXEC MyProcedure(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',row.values), axis=1)
#2
df.apply(lambda row: cursor.execute('EXEC MyProcedure?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?',row.values), axis=1)
#3
df.apply(lambda row: cursor.execute("""EXEC MyProcedure(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",row.values), axis=1)
results = list(cursor.fetchall())
#4
df.apply(lambda row: cursor.execute(text('EXEC MyProcedure(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',row.values)), axis=1)
#5
df.apply(lambda row: cursor.execute('EXEC MyProcedure',row.values), axis=1)
cursor.close()
```

`cursor.callproc()` is not supported here, so I have to go through an `EXEC` or `CALL` request.
So i believe it is coming from my parameters handling somehow but I don't know how to tackle it. As I have 57 parameters I am trying to avoid to have to name all the parameters as much as possible ...
My first wish was to make the code run any procedure by passing the procedure name as a paramater of my python function, but as it failed to run, I went to something supposively easier. 
The procedure has been executed directly on the database through SQL Server Management and works fine.

Comment: What kind of object is "engine"? I think the error message indicates a problem with the parameters to the execute() method. Also, if your proc uses 57(!) parameters, there may be a design issue there.

Comment: engine is a sqlalchemy engine. It has 57 parameters because the table has 57 columns

Comment: That's why I suggested a redesign.  Generally, you should not pass a row to a proc, column by column.   Imagine that you add (or remove) a column.  All your code has to change.  much better to pass a key to the proc and let it get the row on its own, if possible.

Comment: Which dialect/DBAPI option are you using? PyODBC

mxODBC

pymssql

zxJDBC for Jython

adodbapi? I'm wondering if it might be an encoding problem

Comment: I use pyodbc lastest driver version

Comment: Actually after consideration we dropped the idea of using stored procedures.... but thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially simplify things by using pyodbc's `Cursor#executemany` method:

```python
cnxn = engine.raw_connection()
cnxn.autocommit = True
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

# prepare test environment
crsr.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable")  # clear previous test data, if any
# prepare test data
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 'Alfa'), (2, 'Bravo')], columns=['id', 'txt'])

sql = "{CALL MyProcedure (?, ?)}"
rows = df.itertuples(index=False)
crsr.executemany(sql, rows)

# verify results
results = crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable").fetchall()
print(results)
# [(1, 'Alfa'), (2, 'Bravo')]
```

Comment: I don't see how it simplifies compared to my `df.apply()` which iterates already over rows